# How to refresh twitter home timeline automatically in an android app to get new twitter feeds asynchronously?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j library and twitter API. I displayed the twitter home timeline in my listview. But now I need help to refresh the list of home timeline in order to get new tweets within a duration of 30 seconds asynchronously.

I did go through these links: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines
https://dev.twitter.com/search/apachesolr_search/refresh%20timeline%20feeds%20automatically

but didn't find the exact answer.

Comment: I got the option that could help me to refresh my listview so that I could get the new twitter updates in listview. here is the link:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-pull-to-refresh.html

Comment: [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-pull-to-refresh.html)

Comment: if anybody of you also get the best than mine please do favour to me by posting your idea.